# Twin primes and Fibonacci

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Let  $ n $ be a positive integer such that  $ 2n+1 $ is prime and  $ n(n+1)\pm 1 $ is a pair of twin primes. Is the Fibonacci number  $ F_{2n+1} $ almost surely prime ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this might be true?

Comment: Because all the examples I considered work. Morally it means that consecutive integers both the sum and the product thereof are as close as possible to the set of primes give rise to Fibonacci numbers themselves as close as possible to this set. It is already known that  $ n\mid m $  implies  $ F_{n}\mid F_{m} $ .

Comment: Please list the first several $n$ that satisfy your criteria ($2n+1$, $n^2+n-1$, and $n^2+n+1$ all prime) and tell us how far out in the list you've checked whether $F_{2n+1}$ is prime.  (If the list is not already in the OEIS, perhaps it should be.)

Comment: $ n=2  :  F_{5}=5\in\P $ ,  $ n=3  :  F_{7}=13\in\P $ ,  $ n=5 :F_{11}=89\in\P $ ,  $ n=6  :  F_{13}=233\in\P $,  $ n=8 :F_{17}=1597\in\P $. I didn't go further.

Comment: Well, that wasn't very many cases....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first several $n$'s for which $2n+1$, $n^2+n-1$, and $n^2+n+1$ are prime are $n=2,3,5,6,8$ and $15$.  It turns out $F_{2n+1}$ is prime in the first five cases (see OEIS entry [A001605](https://oeis.org/A001605)), but

$$F_{31}=1346269=557\times2417$$

The next two values of $n$ are $20$ and $21$, with prime triples $(41,419,421)$ and $(43,461,463)$, respectively.  $F_{43}$ is prime (see the OEIS entry), but

$$F_{41}=165580141=2789\times59369$$

**Added later**:  OEIS entry [A088485](https://oeis.org/A088485) comes in handy here.  It consists of $n$'s for which $n^2+n-1$ and $n^2+n+1$ are twin primes.  The sequence starts

$$2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 15, 20, 21, 24, 38, 41, 50, 54, 59, 66, 89, 101, 131, 138,\ldots$$

Converting it to a sequence of $2n+1$'s and dropping non-primes, we get

$$5,7,11,13,17,31,41,43,83,101,109,179,263,277,\ldots$$

The primes $5,7,11,13,17,43$ and $83$ appear in [A001605](https://oeis.org/A001605); the primes $31,41,101,109,179,263$ and $277$ do not -- i.e., $F_{31},F_{41},F_{101}$, etc. are all *composite*, not prime.

If I had to hazard a guess, I would speculate that it becomes increasingly rare for $n$'s on the OP's list to give a Fibonacci prime $F_{2n+1}$.  Of course it's not known if there are infinitely many twin primes; [nor is it known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime#Known_Fibonacci_primes) if there are infinitely many Fibonacci primes.  It's easy to hazard a guess when little is known.

Comment: $ 14×15-1=209=19×11 $ .

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I was eyeballing for factors and missed the obvious.  I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran a Sage script which has looked at all $n<50000$ for which $2n+1$ and $n(n+1)\pm 1$ are prime and checked for which of them $F_{2n+1}$ is prime as well. Here are the results:

- $F_{2n+1}$ is prime for nine values of $n$, namely:
  $$3,5,6,8,21,41,215,12780,25416\dots$$
- as opposed to $337$ values of $n$ for which $F_{2n+1}$ is composite.

I guess this is evidence *against* your conjecture.

(explanation of last edit: initially I had to finish the computation early because it was taking a lot of time. It has turned out the comptuation was aborted around $n=49400$, so I've decided to finish it. Four more composites were found, no more primes.)

Comment: Thanks Wojowu. Unfortunately I can't accept two answers to the same question....